# Modify ObjectDataProvider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, objectdataprovider

I have an application where I am using a ObjectDataProvider (App.xaml):

```
<Application x:Class="Example.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Example.Settings"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         Startup="Application_Startup"
         DispatcherUnhandledException="ApplicationDispatcherUnhandledException">
<Application.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="odpSettings" ObjectType="{x:Type src:AppSettings}"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

My class is:

```
class AppSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public AppSettings()
    {

    }

    Color itemColor = Colors.Crimson;

public Color ItemColor
    {
        get
        {
            return itemColor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (itemColor == value)
                return;

            itemColor = value;

            this.OnPropertyChanged("ItemColor");
        }
    }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

}

Then I have a userControl where I am using that color, for example:

```
<Border Background="{Binding Source={StaticResource odpSettings}, 
                             Path=ItemColor,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I am adding that UserControl to my MainWindow where I have a ColorPicker control and I would like to modify the Border Background color of my UserControl with the ColorPicker color selected.

I tried something like this:

```
AppSettings objSettings = new AppSettings();
objSettings.ItemColor = colorPicker.SelectedColor;
```

When I change the color using the ColorPicker, the color in my UserControl doesn't change, I guess this is because I am creating a new instance of the class AppSettings.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance.

Alberto

Comment: Can you try setting `Application.Current.Resources["odpSettings"] = new AppSettings();` ?

Comment: Your code won't work at first place because `Background` is of type `Brush` and binded property is of type `Color`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, I used the next code:

```
AppSettings objSettings = (AppSettings)((ObjectDataProvider)Application.Current.FindResource("odpSettings")).ObjectInstance;
```

That way I can access and modify the value of the property ItemColor.

Also I change the property type to SolidColorBrush.

```
objSettings.ItemColor = new SolidColorBrush(colorPicker.SelectedColor);
```